# How with Vue.Draggable make not to sort items inside 1 panel?

Tags: vue.js, draggable, vuedraggable

In my @vue/cli 4.0.5 / vuedraggable 2.24.1 I make 2 panels with elements which can be dragged
from one panel to other, but not sorted inside 1 panel.

Reading docs here https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable
I see example:

```
<draggable
        v-model="list"
        handle=".handle"
        :group="{ name: 'people', pull: 'clone', put: false }"
        ghost-class="ghost"
        :sort="false"
        @change="log"
      >
      <!-- -->
</draggable>
```

and I expect that defining :sort property and with

```
dragOptions() {
    return {
        animation: 0,
        group: "description",
        disabled: !this.enable_tasks_dragging,
        ghostClass: "ghost"
    }
},
```

That result is not I expect :  items can dragged from one panel to other and
sorted inside 1 panel. How to make not to sort items inside 1 panel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the Github page there is a link for all sortable option https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#all-sortable-options. And you obtain this

Import into your project:

```
// Default SortableJS
import Sortable from "sortablejs";
import { Sortable, MultiDrag, Swap, OnSpill, AutoScroll } from "sortablejs";
```

So I think you just have to choose manually the options ( `import{...}` ) that you want

Comment: I added the import line with options. But If I hide most of options : import { /* Sortable, MultiDrag, Swap, OnSpill, */ AutoScroll } from "sortablejs" I still have sorting inside 1 panel. have I to write these options somerhere else ?